# ASP.NET MVC Ajax form check validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to create a form with validation, and if there is no validation errors run some else action.

For example, MyView

```
<div id="myDiv">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "myDiv", }, new {@class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
    ...
}
</div>
```

And MyController,

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Make some Action
            }
            return PartialView("MyView", model);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code I show validation errors in form if there is some. But now I need to run javascript function when there is no validation errors? How could I do it? 
I try to use OnSuccess function of form AjaxOptions, but it run always no matter is there errors or not.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you please Show your View Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC uses jQuery validation and therefore, you need to run jQuery validation method. It is very simple:

```
$('form').valid();
```